# Which is the lightweight linux for virtualbox?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, virtualbox, distro, lightweight-processes

I am completely new to Linux and I want to download and practice linux commands without letting go of my windows pc. I have a Dell Inspiron with 500 GB Hard Drive, 4 GB RAM and Pentium CPU B980 (2.4 GHz) processor with Windows 8.1 on it. I installed virtualbox and downloaded Ubuntu Linux, Linux Mint, Mageia but they all are very slow. I checked all possible answers here and on other sites, but I am unable to make it run faster. I believe it's because all these Linux Distros(This is the fancy word that's used to name them right? ) have graphical interfaces. So is there a linux which comes with only command line interface and is pretty much LIGHTWEIGHT FOR "VIRTUALBOX"?

Thanks

P.S. I am totally new to Linux and I dont even know what it is properly. I just want to install it and practice few commands for now.

Thanks :D

Comment: try to install ubuntu, it is very simple and is more friendly than I know, less than 20GB is enough

Comment: I tried it, but it's very slow. and What do you mean 20 GB? Are you referring to RAM? and I went with recommended settings in virtualbox for ubuntu. I gave 768 MB memory. and 1 CPU(well it's blocked out anyway, I am unable to give more). So Ubuntu is still slow. Even typing commands in it's terminal is slow.

Comment: I was referring to disk space, ubuntu is slow but is really easy to use it and you can remove features to make it lightweight, change the desktop environment o remove it completely, remove services and when you have more experience compile your own kernel to make it even more lightweight

Comment: @downvoters(whoever they maybe, I am not addressing any particular person, I am just saying in general) .My account has been banned from asking questions and the stackoverflow has asked me to review my questions. I don't see how this question is wrong by any means. So if there is any improvement, please suggest so, or else please consider upvoting this question, so I get back my ability to ask questions on this site. I like stackoverflow and would like to be part of this community, so I want your help either in terms of suggestions for re-formatting the question or in form of upvotes. Thanks

Comment: I think that the main problem is that this question is not a real problem and you does not expose any work trying to solve it, I recommend to read the tour again and read `http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html`

Comment: I think that the main problem is that it is a request for recommendations ... which is explicitly off-topic. And such questions attract SPAMMERS; see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try: http://puppylinux.org/

It's running even on my old netbook, your PC should be enough to work with it on VirtualBox.

Comment: Yeah it's working too, but the only thing is that I changed from virtual box to VMware. I have no idea why virtual box had a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want console only, you could try Ubuntu Server. It comes without graphical interface. Or if you want to learn and suffer a bit, you culd try Archlinux:D
Alternatively, you could give a shot to Lubuntu. This last one is my recommendation.
[Lubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#System_Requirements)

Answer (score 1):

I can see that this question has been answered a long time ago but i would like to suggest [**Linux Lite**](http://www.osboxes.org/linux-lite/) as they provide ready-made **virtualbox** and vmware downloads as well . It's based on **Ubuntu LTS** and comes with **Xfce**

Comment: "They", as in Linux Lite, do NOT provide Virtualbox images AFAIK. The Virtualbox images come from a 3rd party site (OSboxes.org as per your link). I don't trust this site so am doing a plain install.

Answer (score 1):

I remember trying to find lightweight VirtualBox images or create them by uninstalling things and customising an image to work with fewer resources, but then I discovered...

**[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)**. I'm afraid it's another thing to install on the host machine, but I think it's pretty small alongside VirtualBox. Vagrant essentially gives a file driven and command line driven interface into VirtualBox, but in some ways the most useful thing are the "boxes". There's [vagrant boxes](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search) for various OSs e.g. versions of ubuntu. They're essentially just images, but specially customised to run in a virtualised minimal command-line only way.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trisquel mini is the best which is also ubuntu based. I am using it. It uses only 200 mb for running os for more information visit my https://hassan004.blogspot.com/2022/01/weight-linux-distro-trisquel-mini.html